# How to edit style of react-clock library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I import this react-clock library in my ReactJS project:
https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-clock

Somehow I can't edit the styles (even after changing *.less files, either in src folder or in the dist folder in the react-clock library under node-modules folder).

How do I change the style of the clock?

Comment: from the repo mentioned: If you don't want to use default React-Clock styling to build upon it, you can import React-Clock by using import Clock from 'react-clock/dist/entry.nostyle'; instead. and I think you can pass in the custom className and edit from your css.

Comment: I have tried to use  <code>import Clock from 'react-clock/dist/entry.nostyle'</code>, but I am not sure how to edit the styles after that. Can you explain in more detailed steps? Like where should I put the css file, how do I access the classNames, and which classNames do I refer to? Many thanks.